# Checking if entry uploaded/exists in table using C# securely using AWS IAM

Tags: database, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I need to check if a value has successfully uploaded to a table using C#. The table uses a hash and range. Currently I use a queryrequest->queryresponse->queryresult and then check if the result is null. However the problem with this is that the entire table entry (i.e. all fields) are passed back to the program. This is not sufficiently secure.

I have looked at AWS IAM access policies however I cannot seem to restrict 'getitem' to field level, only to table level.

Any suggestions as to how to have an IAM access policy that only allows users get the hash/range from a table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible via IAM.  However, one way to approximate it is to encrypt all fields except for the hash/range.